# Weird python behavior when redirecting output to file (when using os.system)

Tags: python, redirectstandardoutput

I got a problem that I think related to the low level of how the redirecting output (operator `>`) and `os.system` work

***PROBLEM***
This is my code. I want to get the 2 last line of bunch of text file. It works fine, but how the output is organized confused me

```
import os

# Get list directory within the root directory
root_list_dir = [directory for directory in os.listdir(".") if  os.path.isdir(directory)]

for directory in root_list_dir:
    log_path = directory + "/acoustic_model/log/"
    log_list = os.listdir(log_path)

    for i in log_list:
        print("==============================")
        os.system("tail -n 2 " + log_path + "" + i)
```

Standard output when I called `python my_script.py` (It worked as my expectation. I cut off most of the output since it's redundant):

```
==============================
2018-03-09 00:06:46,594     INFO           main: Develop: DNN -- MCD: 4.891 dB; BAP: 0.185 dB; F0:- RMSE: 26.193 Hz; CORR: 0.794; VUV: 6.372%
2018-03-09 00:06:46,594     INFO           main: Test   : DNN -- MCD: 4.721 dB; BAP: 0.163 dB; F0:- RMSE: 22.119 Hz; CORR: 0.828; VUV: 6.052%
==============================
2018-03-23 17:08:31,564     INFO         labels: loaded /data/thinhnv20/merlin-master/egs/build_your_own_voice/s1/experiments/doanngocle_cutaudio_3k5/test_synthesis/gen-lab/TTS8.lab, 84552 labels
2018-03-23 17:08:32,276     INFO         labels: loaded /data/thinhnv20/merlin-master/egs/build_your_own_voice/s1/experiments/doanngocle_cutaudio_3k5/test_synthesis/gen-lab/TTS7.lab, 82456 labels
==============================
2018-05-18 21:05:26,605     INFO           main: reconstructing waveform(s)
2018-05-18 21:05:26,605     INFO wav_generation: creating waveform for    1 of    1: labspit1
==============================
2018-05-18 21:57:58,600     INFO wav_generation: creating waveform for    1 of    2: labspit1
2018-05-18 21:58:25,779     INFO wav_generation: creating waveform for    2 of    2: labspit2
==============================
2018-05-05 03:06:25,523     INFO           main: Develop: DNN -- MCD: 4.981 dB; BAP: 0.187 dB; F0:- RMSE: 27.926 Hz; CORR: 0.766; VUV: 6.610%
2018-05-05 03:06:25,524     INFO           main: Test   : DNN -- MCD: 4.832 dB; BAP: 0.166 dB; F0:- RMSE: 23.796 Hz; CORR: 0.797; VUV: 6.385%
==============================
2018-05-18 22:04:01,253     INFO wav_generation: creating waveform for    2 of    3: labspit1
2018-05-18 22:04:28,330     INFO wav_generation: creating waveform for    3 of    3: labspit2
==============================
2018-03-10 20:50:44,003     INFO           main: Develop: DNN -- MCD: 4.892 dB; BAP: 0.182 dB; F0:- RMSE: 26.413 Hz; CORR: 0.790; VUV: 6.383%
2018-03-10 20:50:44,003     INFO           main: Test   : DNN -- MCD: 4.717 dB; BAP: 0.161 dB; F0:- RMSE: 21.953 Hz; CORR: 0.832; VUV: 6.134%
==============================
2018-03-13 09:23:05,873     INFO wav_generation: creating waveform for   31 of   32: TTS8
2018-03-13 09:23:08,908     INFO wav_generation: creating waveform for   32 of   32: TTS9
```

But when I redirected the output to a file (by calling `python my_script.py > results`), the `===============` part is always print at the end of the `results`:

```
2018-03-13 14:57:24,852     INFO wav_generation: creating waveform for   31 of   32: TTS8
2018-03-13 14:57:27,999     INFO wav_generation: creating waveform for   32 of   32: TTS9
2018-03-13 15:09:45,300     INFO wav_generation: creating waveform for   31 of   32: TTS8
2018-03-13 15:09:48,499     INFO wav_generation: creating waveform for   32 of   32: TTS9
2018-03-13 14:25:32,699     INFO           main: Develop: DNN -- MCD: 4.875 dB; BAP: 0.183 dB; F0:- RMSE: 26.291 Hz; CORR: 0.792; VUV: 6.487%
2018-03-13 14:25:32,700     INFO           main: Test   : DNN -- MCD: 4.716 dB; BAP: 0.162 dB; F0:- RMSE: 22.129 Hz; CORR: 0.830; VUV: 6.132%
==============================
==============================
==============================
==============================
==============================
==============================
==============================
==============================
==============================
==============================
```

Can anyone explain to me something wrong here? I would love to hear any information!
Thanks in advance

Comment: To achieve what you want, this is not perfect but it might works.
Make file which contains "===========" name as 'line.file'.
Change inside of loop as follow.
os.system("cat line.file")
os.system("tail -n 2 " + log_path + "" + i)

Comment: @ilkyutonylee Same result, or did I misunderstand your idea? Can you explain a bit further?

Comment: Ah I see your edit now, thanks for your clarification

Comment: Badly, I tried but the result was same. I changed first row and second row in loop, finally it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two things writing to stdout, both with their own buffers.

This is one of the many reasons you usually don't want to use [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system).

You can force Python to flush it output after each [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) just by using the `flush=True` argument. Or you can even `open(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'wb', buffering=0)` and then `write` your own `bytes` to that to disable buffering.

But that may or may not be sufficient, because you still won't have any control over what `os.system` writes. If you want to make sure its output is either unbuffered, or shares the same buffers as Python, there's no way around that except using [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). As the docs for `os.system` said to do in the first place.

So:

```
for i in log_list:
    print("==============================")
    proc = subprocess.run(['tail', '-n', '2', log_path + i], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print(proc.stdout)
```

Comment: I think I get your idea, I will read some docs about `subprocess`. One more thing that make me concern: If there are more than one buffer, the output must be mixed, right? Why they are good as expected when I leave it to stdout, but when it come to file the `===` appear at the end? It's weird to me

Comment: @enamoria The default buffering in Python is line-by-line when stdout is going to a TTY (the terminal), but chunk-by-chunk (typically something like 4K, but it depends on your Python version and platform) when it's not (redirected to a file). Many other programs—including `tail` and the shell—also distinguish on isatty.

Comment: @enamoria That's why I changed the code to just capture all of the output from `tail` into a string and then `print` it—that way we don't have to worry about how the buffers actually work, because there's only the one buffer, Python's. If you prefer to disable buffering or manually flush things, you can (and sometimes you need to, for efficiency, or for keeping up "real-time" output), but it's easier to get wrong.